# If "fn = new Fn()", why changing Fn.prototype after fn instantiation doesn't change fn.__proto__?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Take this code for example:

```js
function Fn() {}
Fn.prototype = {
  isIt: true
};

let fn = new Fn();

Fn.prototype = {
  isIt: false
}

console.log(fn.isIt); // true
```

When we use new keyword to instantiate a new function, one of the things that happen under the hood is that the prototype of the fn gets "**LINKED**" to the prototype of Fn. so it's not a copy and for example if we try to run a method on fn which sits on Fn.prototype it executes the code via that object. so i'm just a bit confused about this.

Comment: An object created using `new` maintains a reference to the prototype that was used to create it. If you completely _replace_ `Fn.prototype` with something else, then this will have no effect on `fn`. If you _modify_ `Fn.prototype`, then this will affect `fn`.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks, exactly what i wasn't paying attention to.

Answer (score 0):

> When the code new Foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from *Foo.prototype*.
> 2. The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments, and with this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is
>    equivalent to new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is
>    called without arguments.
> 3. The object (not null, false, 3.1415 or other primitive types) returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole
>    new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return
>    an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead. (Normally
>    constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if
>    they want to override the normal object creation process.) - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

You see the object created here is inherited from *Foo.prototype*, so if you change it latter, it has no effects on inherited objects.